# Ecto: How to update and insert association in one update using put_assoc

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to write a single changeset that will update a model and insert an association. I cannot find examples on how to use [`put_assoc/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4)

```
  order = order
    |> Proj.Order.changeset(%{state: "error", error_count: order.error_count + 1})
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(
      :order_errors,
      [Proj.OrderError.changeset(%Proj.OrderError{}, %{reason: "not_found"})])
    |> Proj.Repo.update!
```

This prints out the following error:

```
** (Ecto.InvalidChangesetError) could not perform update because changeset is invalid.

* Changeset changes

%{order_errors: [%Ecto.Changeset{action: :insert, changes: %{id: nil, inserted_at: nil, order_id: nil, reason: "not_found", updated_at: nil}, constraints: [], errors: [order_id: "can't be blank"], filters: %{}, model: %Proj.OrderError{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built>, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, order: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :order is not loaded>, order_id: nil, reason: nil, updated_at: nil}, optional: [], opts: [], params: %{"reason" => "not_found"}, prepare: [], repo: nil, required: [:order_id, :reason], types: %{id: :id, inserted_at: Ecto.DateTime, order_id: :id, reason: :string, updated_at: Ecto.DateTime}, valid?: false, validations: []}], state: "error"}

* Changeset params

%{"error_count" => 1, "state" => "error"}

* Changeset errors

[]
```

Any examples I can look at for `put_assoc/4`? How can I find why the changeset is invalid?

The goal of doing things this way is that I hope the new `order` would have `order_errors` preloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found how to make it work in the [Ecto tests](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/430545ceaf9506b231203f1c148e174d11a9ecb4/test/ecto/repo/has_assoc_test.exs#L40-L46). Short story, simply remove the `changeset` creation and use directly a new model.

```
  order = order
    |> Proj.Order.changeset(%{state: "error", error_count: order.error_count + 1})
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(
      :order_errors,
      [%Proj.OrderError{reason: "not_found"}])
    |> Proj.Repo.update!
```

I'd still like to know how to understand the error message from the original post

Answer (score 0):

As [put_assoc/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4) describes the valid value:

> The given value may either be the association struct, a changeset for the given association or a map or keyword list of changes to be applied to the current association. On all cases, it is expected the keys to be atoms. If a map or keyword list are given and there is no association, one will be created.

If you use the `changeset`, you should use the existed `%Proj.OrderError{}`, the `put_assoc/4` will auto do the `update` for this `changeset`.

But to other situation, especially the record need `insert`, use `struct` 
 ,keyword lists or map is better idea.